# Hamming Distance as integer return of two Strings Java

Tags: java, string, algorithm

In order to compute the hamming distance of two strings, they must both have the same length. 
What can be returned if this kind of algorithmn is implemented in java, if the strings are different lengths?

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit? Without a little bit more background, it's hard to tell what you're asking.

Comment: The Hamming distance of two strings of different length is undefined.

Comment: Since Hamming distance is a metric, and therefore nonnegative, if you wanted to simply indicate failed arguments without using an exception you could just return -1 and handle appropriately. It depends on your needs.

Comment: Why i have been downvoted??? Explain yourself

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135/encouraging-people-to-explain-downvotes

Comment: I guess the problem is that your logic is faulty: "In order to compute the hamming distance of two strings, they must both have the same length." Correct. "What should I do if the the strings have different lengths?" That's the wrong question. You can't possibly do anything because of the observation you made beforehand. The question that logically arises is why you would possibly want to compute something that you yourself admitted is undefined.

Comment: @NiklasB. It could be, that there is some kind of behavior pattern in this case. I didn't know so i asked for the handling. I know that the logic is faulty, and that has caused my EDIT:

Comment: @StefanSprenger: The behaviour is what *you* define it to be. You're basically asking a design question, but your question is formulated like a technical question. By the way, a good answer is probably something along the lines of "raise an exception and blame the user".

Comment: @NiklasB. Manchmal ist Intelligenz ein Fluch

Comment: @StefanSprenger: I can't relate.

Comment: @NiklasB. I edited my question. Your objections were justified.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is in your question:

> In order to compute the hamming distance of two strings, they must both have the same length

Otherwise - you cannot compute it (it is undefined)!

Regarding what you can return, it depends on your needs. You can return whatever you want. If you do not want to do things like [Pairwise alignment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_alignment#Pairwise_alignment), I can offer you two simple metrics:

Given two strings, the shorter of length x and the other of length y:

1. Compare the shortest string with the prefix of length x of the longer string by hamming distance, and add (y-x). As though you padded your shorter string with $ or some other special character.
2. Similarly, take the lowest hamming distance from all the possible padding options of the shorter string from the right and from the left with special char (e.g., $).

Answer (score 5):

If the strings are different lengths, then the Hamming Distance is not defined.

What you'd probably want in that case is the [Levenshtein Distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance).

Comment: So a solution would be to return the Levenshtein Distance if it's not usable by the Hemming Distance?

Comment: @StefanSprenger Depends on your needs. However notice that for Levenshtein Distance is not equivalent to Hamming Distance for every two strings of the same length.

Comment: @GariBN What could be returned then if I have a "HemmingMethod"

Comment: What you return would depend on the specific behavior you'd want. However, it would make a lot of sense to throw an IllegalArgumentException in this case, described in the documentation as "Thrown to indicate that a method has been passed an illegal or inappropriate argument. "

Comment: @StefanSprenger I edited my answer below. Take a look.